# Твоя(,) и только твоя

Tags: пунктуация

Как вы считаете, нужна ли указанная запятая: "Это твоя проблема. Твоя(,) и только твоя".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Это твоя проблема. **Твоя, и только твоя**.*

Правило Розенталя: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=105#pp105

3. Если оборот **с повторяющимся словом** присоединяется союзом и, то перед союзом **ставится запятая**, а при подчеркивании присоединяемой конструкции — тире: Суд руководствуется **законом, и только законом**; **Ты, и только ты** можешь сделать это; Да, и только да!; Факты, и только факты могут подтвердить сказанное; В этом, и только в этом заключается правда; Это была победа — и важная победа; Он выигрывал — и как выигрывал!

Но (без интонации присоединения): Через три точки, не принадлежащие одной прямой, проходит одна и только одна плоскость.